# How to remove an eventhandler document.onkeydown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, I would need programmatically overridde or remove onkeydown from document (for example using a simple condition)

```
document.onkeydown = function (f) {
    myMethod();
};
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
document.onkeydown = null
```

You could use jquery to do your event handeling for you, the method you use is less commonly used and doesn't allow multiple subscribers.

Look at the documentation here:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

example:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(){
    doStuff();
})
// unsubscribe all handlers
$(document).off("keydown");
```

Comment: could you post a jquery version please?

Comment: `document.onkeydown` is certainly old but is standardized and works in all major browsers, including IE 6-8, and will continue to work in future browsers. Why do you think it is bad practice to use it?

Comment: OP doesn't _have_ to use jQuery, they could use the accepted standard of `document.addEventListener('keydown', function() {...})` https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener

Comment: @TimDown You are right, i just think it's less commonly used, i will modify my answer

Comment: @MrMisterMan imho, that **would** actually be bad practice, because then you will have to manually manage the cross browser differences.

Comment: If I was already using jQuery (which most people are) I would of course use the `$(document).on()` method. My point is that you don't need to load an entire library to achieve this.

Comment: @MrMisterMan That is true, but the OP did ask for a specific jQuery version :)

Comment: Is it better to assign to `null` or `undefined`?

Answer (score 8):

You can remove it with:

```
document.onkeydown = null;
```

If you want to be able to restore it, you can save it into a variable first:

```
var saved_keydown = document.onkeydown;
document.onkeydown = null;
//... later
document.onkeydown = saved_keydown;
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is set it to null

```
document.onkeydown = null;
```

Comment: well, this answer is a bit late for about 57 secs to @Willem D'haeseleer

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove it, you can only attach a new one that does nothing, like :

```
document.onkeydown = function () {};
```

with jQuery you can do:

```
$(document).on('keydown', myMethod);
```

and to remove

```
$(document).off('keydown', myMethod);
```

Comment: i would use `document.onkeydown = null` no need to keep a reference to an unnecessary empty function

Comment: Empty functions are great!